# change pattern of cols with same name in purrr::map_dfc R

Tags: r, dictionary, purrr

I have a function that generates a dataframe with 2 cols (X and Y).
I want to use map_dfc but I would like to change the suffixes "...1", "...2" and so on that appear because the col names are the same

I would like something as (X_df1, Y_df1, X_df2, Y_df2, ...). Is there a suffix parameter? I've read the documentation and couldn't find

I don't want to use `map_dfr` because I need the dataframe to be wide.

```
example_function <- function(n1,n2){
  
  tibble(X = n1+n2,
         Y = n1*n2)
  
}

values <- tibble(n1 = c(1,2),
                 n2 = c(5,6))

map2_dfc(values$n1, values$n2, example_function)
```

gives me

```
A tibble: 1 x 4
  X...1 Y...2 X...3 Y...4
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     6     5     8    12
```

And I want

```
A tibble: 1 x 4
  X_df1 Y_df1 X_df2 Y_df2
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     6     5     8    12
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If we don't want to change the function, we can `rename` before binding the cols - use `pmap` to loop over the rows the data, apply the function (`example_function`), loop over the `list` with `imap`, rename all the columns of the `list` of `tibble`s with the `list` index and then use `bind_cols`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
pmap(values, example_function) %>%
    imap(~ {nm1 <- str_c('_df', .y)
    rename_with(.x, ~ str_c(., nm1), everything())
   }) %>% 
  bind_cols
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 1 × 4
  X_df1 Y_df1 X_df2 Y_df2
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     6     5     8    12
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just build the new names first and apply them after you call `map2_dfc()`:

```r
library(purrr)
library(tibble)

example_function <- function(n1,n2){
  
  tibble(X = n1+n2,
         Y = n1*n2)
  
}

values <- tibble(n1 = c(1,2),
                 n2 = c(5,6))


new_names <- lapply(seq_len(ncol(values)), function(x) paste0(c("X", "Y"), "_df", x)) %>% 
  unlist()

map2_dfc(values$n1, values$n2, example_function) %>% 
  setNames(new_names) 
#> New names:
#> * X -> X...1
#> * Y -> Y...2
#> * X -> X...3
#> * Y -> Y...4
#> # A tibble: 1 x 4
#>   X_df1 Y_df1 X_df2 Y_df2
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     6     5     8    12
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>